# image optimization reduce the loading time?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-optimization

Today i messed up with UIImageView. Actually i was tried to add (15.5MB)sized image into UIImageView. using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext i successfully added the image(Process is bit slow because of large sized image).

After that i tried to change the brightness and contrast of the image using [ThisCode](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters)

Because of large image size, filters also working bit slowly :-<.

i am worried about the loading time taken.

Now i have **question**, will image optimisation reduces the time taken to process??  i know it will reduce the size of the image. will it reduce the time taken for loading image into uiimageview?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

```
UIImage *originalImage = ...;
CGSize destinationSize = ...;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. i have edited my question. Please have a look around that. i was succeed to show the image. but the loading time is more., is it possible to reduce the loading time?

Answer (score 0):

Talking about reducing size this function works far better:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

Call this method like this:

```
UIImage *thumbnailImage =[self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100,100)];
```

For the filtering use: GPUFilters

[GPUFilters](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Comment: thanks Puru. my question is about image optimisation. can you please tell me if i am using optimised image will that reduce the processing time.?

Comment: @dhanush :  Obviously presently i am working on the same issues dear.

Comment: i tried with GPUImageFilters. The image return from the filter is not good. pixel problems are coming. What to do now?

Comment: @dhanush: will you please show your code where you are cropping image after taking it from UIImagePicker ?